# Pixel Shader with multiple textures − How to get better performance?

Tags: c#, performance, xna, hlsl

I'm actually making a little 3D game using C# and xna. As some things are getting rather slow, I'm starting to optimize these things.

I have a pixel shader which uses multiple textures/samplers :

```
texture MountainTexture;
texture GrassTexture;
texture IceTexture;
texture SandTexture;
sampler moutain = sampler_state {
   texture = (MountainTexture);
   MinFilter = Linear;
   MagFilter = Linear;
   MipFilter = Linear;
   AddressU = Wrap;
   AddressV = Wrap;
};
sampler ice = sampler_state {
   texture = (IceTexture);
   ...
};
sampler grass = sampler_state {
   texture = (GrassTexture);
   ...
};
sampler sand = sampler_state {
   texture = (SandTexture);
   ...
};
```

The pixel shader function uses one or two of these samplers for each pixel rendered. I noticed that, when I let the shader use only one of these samplers for every pixel, the framerate is improved with a ~ x2 factor.

So I was wondering :
- what exactly does the GPU when I use tex2D on multiple samplers in the same shader ? Why is it that slow ?
- What is the difference between passing textures with `Shader.Parameters["myTexture"].SetValue(myTexture)` and `GraphicsDevices.Texture[10] = myTexture` ?

Is there a way to improve performance when using a shader with multiple samplers ? (my textures are too big to put them all in a single texture).

Thank you very much !

Comment: Before somebody else pops in with "[premature optimization](https://www.google.com/search?q=premature+optimization)", I'm gonna.

Comment: My scene runs at 30fps, which is really bad. And I didn't put all I wanted to put in it yet. So I think I really need to optimize now :)

Comment: 60 -> 30 fps sounds like vsync is on. Did you try it with vsync off? (that won't solve the issue of course, but it may give a more useful benchmark)

Comment: I already disabled vsync. This is really a ~x2 factor. :)
I think this has to do with time-consuming state changes but I want to understand how exactly it works and when the state changes occurs. I searched a lot but did not find anything usefull...

Comment: Do your have mipmaps with your textures? That generally speeds up sampling by a pretty good factor.

Comment: Yes, i have mipmaps. I reduced texture size and put all the textures in one atlas texture, but it is still rather slow to access. So I tried to generate procedurally the textures, and, even with 2 fractals, a perlin noise and a bunch of other calculations, it is still faster than sampling... I didn't imagine sampling was so slow !

Answer (score 0):

"(my textures are too big to put them all in a single texture)"

I'd say you found your problem. Huge textures.

Might I suggest using some sort of shader like uvDetective from http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/webpages/shader_library.html to fnd out what size your textures really need to be. I suspect that you have every possible knob turned to 11. Don't do that. It's a game.